# Converting Binned Values into Categorical

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am working on the Titanic Dataset(Kaggle) competition. One of the columns in the dataset is Fare, which contains float values. For EDA I have converted the Fare columns into bins, and assigned labels to the bins. The problem is that some of the labels are assigned to np.nan.

```
  Fare          1284 non-null float64
```

Some sample Values:

```
  0     7.2500
  1    71.2833
  2     7.9250
  3    53.1000
  4     8.0500
```

When I convert the Fare column into bins using qcut:

```
      dataset['FareBin'] = pd.qcut(dataset['Fare'], 4)
```

Output:

```
      (-0.001, 7.896]      337
      (14.054, 30.071]     322
      (30.071, 512.329]    320
      (7.896, 14.054]      305
```

The problem arises when I want to assign labels to the FareBin column

```
       label1=[1,2,3,4]
       bin1=[-0.001,7.896,14.054,30.071,512.329]
       dataset['FareBin']=pd.cut(dataset['Fare'],bin1,labels=label1)
```

I don't know what the problem is. Also if there is a better way to do this please tell me.
Thanks for taking the time to go through this.

Comment: I just replicated your code with the Titanic dataset and it runs fine for me. What problem exactly do you observe?

Comment: The farebin column contains missing values, please check once.

Comment: Okay I thought of that as a solution. But I don't understand why it happened as I covered all the ranges for the fare column

Comment: As far as I see it is only one single sample (#1043) where the value for "Fare" is missing. Just impute that and you are good to go.

Comment: If your matter is solved I suggest you mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one sample in the dataset where the fare is missing (#1043).

Impute for example like that and then bin the values:

```
display(df[df.fare.isna()])

age     cabin   embarked    fare    name    parch   passengerid     pclass  sex     sibsp   survived    ticket
1043    60.50000    cabin_unknown   S   nan     Storey, Mr. Thomas  0   1044    3   male    0   nan     3701
```

Finding similar passengers:

```
filtered_df = df[(df.pclass == 3) & (df.embarked == "S") & (df.sex == "male") & (df.sibsp == 0) & 
                (df.parch == 0) & (df.age > 50) & (df.age < 70) & (~df.survived.isna())]
```

Output:

```
    age     cabin   embarked    fare    name    parch   passengerid     pclass  sex     sibsp   survived    ticket
94      59.00000    NaN     S   7.25000     Coxon, Mr. Daniel   0   95  3   male    0   0.00000     364500
152     55.50000    NaN     S   8.05000     Meo, Mr. Alfonzo    0   153     3   male    0   0.00000     A.5. 11206
222     51.00000    NaN     S   8.05000     Green, Mr. George Henry     0   223     3   male    0   0.00000     21440
326     61.00000    NaN     S   6.23750     Nysveen, Mr. Johan Hansen   0   327     3   male    0   0.00000     345364
406     51.00000    NaN     S   7.75000     Widegren, Mr. Carl/Charles Peter    0   407     3   male    0   0.00000     347064
631     51.00000    NaN     S   7.05420     Lundahl, Mr. Johan Svensson     0   632     3   male    0   0.00000     347743
```

Fill in the missing value:

```
df.fare.fillna(filtered_df.fare.mean(), inplace=True)
```

Be aware that I have lowercased all column names in the dataset. You need to adjust that for your code accordingly.